# table numbers wrongly placed

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Although I am using a separate chapter for the appendix the table numbers that belong to appendix have the number as they belong to conclusion part.
The figures below shows the problem:

[image]

[image]

SO the figure that have numbers starting with 5. are all in the appendix part but still take number 5 in front which is for the conclusion part. So, they should normal have 6.1, 6.2 etc. How can I change them?

I am using the below codes in the main body and appendix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}   % language, change USenglish to german if writing in German
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs} % math symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}   % package for graphics
\usepackage{tabularx}   % package for tables
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{microtype} 
%\usepackage{bookmark}  % allows you to click on bookmarks in the pdf, it is commented off because it might disturb you at the beginning. Comment on to see what it can do.
\usepackage{array, booktabs, xltabular} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}         % for bold math
\usepackage{listings}   % for inserting code
\usepackage{verbatim}   % useful for program listings
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % turning wide pages by 90°
\usepackage{color}      % package for colors
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}   % interface of your document dimensions
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % option hang produces hanging footnotes, see options of package
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}  % defines the position of a caption in a floating environment
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}
\usepackage{longtable} % for long tables
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{makecell} % use for bold line \hlineB{2}
\usepackage{boldline} % use for bold line \hlineB{2}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{rotating} % to retrun tables vertically 
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{footnote} 
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{url} %for online cite
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ltcaption}
%% Customized options
\newlength{\tempdima}





\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   % Either double-spaced, onehalf-spaced, or single-spaced
\clubpenalty=1000                       % prevents single lines at the end of page 
\widowpenalty=1000                      % prevents single lines at the top of page 
\displaywidowpenalty=1000               % for math mode
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000         % prevents footnotes from breaking across pages
\newcommand{\N}{{\mathbb N}}            % shortcut for natural numbers
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}            % shortcut for real numbers
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

%% Other stuff
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg} % include pictures only with these endings
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}   % defines the space of hanging footnotes

\geometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm} %sets margins on paper itself, check again before submitting/writing if you got the right numbers here
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{51, 51, 178}    % defines colour of written text
\allowdisplaybreaks % allows page breaks in align envirnonment



\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Arbnor/Desktop/thesisn/write/fig/}}




\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}


\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \small    
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1
}

\begin{titlepage} 

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 

\center 

\includegraphics{logo.pdf}


\textsc{\LARGE }\\[1.5cm] 


\textsc{\Large }\\[0.5cm] 



\HRule\\[0.4cm]

{\huge\bfseries }\\[0.4cm] 

\HRule\\[1.5cm]


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \large
        \textit{Author}\\
        \textsc{ } % Your name
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \large
        \textit{Supervisor}\\
        \textsc{ } % Supervisor's name
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}



\vfill\vfill\vfill 

{\large\today} 


\vfill 

\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\clearpage\null\newpage

\newpage

\include{chapters/abstract}
\newpage


\tableofcontents


\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}



\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}



\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapters/introduction}



\include{chapters/Literature}

\include{chapters/data}

\include{chapters/Analysis}


\include{chapters/conclusion}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{references/references}







\newpage
\include{chapters/appendix}



\include{originality/originality}
\end{document}


and the appendix is:

\chapter*{Appendix} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}


\begin{table}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\tempdima=\dimexpr \textwidth/7 - 2\tabcolsep\relax
\small
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Sample window} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Actual crises} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Correctly predicted} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Missed crises} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Actual non-crises} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Correctly predicted} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Wrongly called}  \\ 

\midrule 
         &             &                  &             &  &                   &               \\
          &            &                    &             &                 &                   &              \\

\midrule 
Total         &            &                  &             &                &                 &             \\

\midrule 

Percentage    & \%       & \%              & \%         & \%            & \%               & \%          \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
\caption{1-year ahead overall out-of-sample performance}
\label{table:1yaovoutsaperformance}
\end{table}
```

Comment: what is the intention of `\textsc{\LARGE }\\[1.5cm] ` ?  the `\textsc{\LARGE }` does nothing at all (just switches to a large small caps font then switches back again without using it) and the `\\[1.5cm]` is an error.

Comment: The tables are numbered within chapters but you have used `\chapter*` for the appendix so they use the last numbered chapter. You could change that but using a numbered (or lettered)  chapter for the appendix would be most common. Also please fix the example so it demonstrates the problem, you have posted a lot of code but no one can run it as posted

Comment: If you really want 6 then just put `\refstepcounter{chapter}` at the start of the appendix but since there is no chapter 6 it will look a bit odd.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I use `\\[3em]` and so all the time to leave some vertical space before the next paragraph.

Comment: @vonbrand but the usage is completely wrong and must generate errors and warnings. `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph is wrong (and generates underful box of maximum 10000 badness) but you have  `\textsc{\Large }\\[0.5cm]` but `\textsc{\Large }` does nothing at all as it is just two font changes but not text, so the `\\ ` is at the start of a paragraph so will give errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want 6 then just put

```
\refstepcounter{chapter}
```

at the start of the appendix but since there is no chapter 6 it will look a bit odd.